# Does MongooseJS return a new fresh result object on save()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

By default MongoDB on collection.save() returns a WriteResult object as stated in the documentation:

`The save() returns a WriteResult object that contains the status of the insert or update operation.`

But with Mongoose (and I guess the underlying mongodb driver in node) you can add a second parameter that is populated with the entire object that you just inserted and with the new _id:

```
var user = new User(req.body);

user.save(function (err, userResult) {
    if (err) {
        log.error(err);
    }
    log.debug('User data: ', userResult);
});
```

So my question: 
Does `userResult` contain retrieved data from Mongo and it's a fresh object OR is the object passed already passed into the save() method and from the database call is merged with only some partial data like the generated _id and/or created date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at `Model.prototype.save()`:

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/8cb0e35/lib/model.js#L254

It looks like you get back the same model instance (`self`) in your `userResult`.

Comment: I'm using 3.8 .. and I don't understand what is happening https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/model.js#L167

Comment: It's still returning the same `self` and `numAffected`, but it's using promises internally. There's a `complete` function in `Model.prototype.save()`, created via the `handleSave` helper method. When this called, as long as the first err param is null, it will resolve the same way. You can see it here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/model.js#L133

Comment: I made some tests and I have this piece of code:

    var bigMessage = '{ ... 4kb of data here .. }';
    var message = new Message(bigMessage);
    message.save(function (err, theMessage) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
      console.log('message: ', theMessage);
    });

Using `mongostat` I see these values in the netIn netOut section:
netIn 5k
netOut 4k

Doesn't this mean that the data is returned back to the node app?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the object returned is a new object -- not the original one (so `user` != `userResult`)

Mongoose supports a few [options](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-mongooseOptions) -- `new: true` and `lean: false` settings may be of interest to you to modify how data is returned in different operations (if you want it to be a new option or do not care).

You can verify this 'new object' is the case by using the following:

```
var user = new User(req.body);

user.save(function (err, userResult) {
    if (err) {
        log.error(err);
    }

    user.name = 'TEST';
    console.log(`${userResult.name} will be undefined but ${user.name} will not be`);
    log.debug('User data: ', userResult);
});
```